# Can <span> receive data from a database or only <input> can?

Tags: html, laravel, web, input, bootstrap-4

Can a `<span>` tag receive data from a database or only an `<input>` field?

I'm working on a frontend school project and I would like to know if `<input>` is the only that can receive data from a database?

The backend is using Laravel.

Comment: I see someone voted down your question, but they didn't offer any guidance.  Not cool.  Your question is ... not answerable.  It would be like me asking a carpenter what type of shingles to use on my patio furniture.  (For the record, I don't do down votes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems either you don't understand the way web app works or have meshed up your question to make good sense. what I understood from your question is you want to display content of your database through either `span` or `input` tag. so the answer is both can take content from database but the difference is, front end user cannot change content of `span` but with `input` it is possible, also if you want to send updated data back to server, to update content of your database through `form` tag you can do with `input` and is not possible with `span`. It's kind of situational which one to use.

And of course this is not the place for such kind of questions kindly go through some good tutorial for such stuff.

Comment: You're Welcome! but next time try with some debugging related question  not kind of opinionated type question, stack overflow is not a discussion forum. thanks.